# How to reuse c# first-code migrations in a new environment?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Using GitHub I move the development of my solution between different computers, so I need to setup a new local-DB on any new machine on which I develop. I'm stuck at how to reuse those migrations.cs so I can rerun all of them on a new local-DB created on the machine. Keep in mind that mine is a .Net Core 2 solution, so many normal automation tools of VS are out of my sight and I'm left with Add-Migration and Update-Database so far. Searching online returns only answers of common use unfortunately.

Comment: Target migration maybe

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a kind of solution, you just need to re-target the update-database to the first migration(0):

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:0
```